# How to restrict users to watch Videos using AEC Membership(Account Expiration Control Component) in joomla?

Tags: php, video, joomla, membership

i had develop a video site.
In this site Free user should watch only free videos.
If they want see other videos they must subscribe to paid membership plan.
How can i do it. 
i have AEC Membership(Account Expiration Control Component).
pls advise it..!!
My site is http://yogamother.com

Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [the authors](http://www.valanx.org/) are hiding all of the documentation behind their registration system.

Without free and open access to the manuals, it's going to be hard for anyone without first-hand experience with the system to be too much help.  All I could find is [this quickstart guide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/3945724/AEC-Quickstart) that someone was nice enough to publish on Scribd.

Good luck, you're going to need it.

Comment: My Dear Charles ...!! thanks for ur kind help...!! But that links are not help me...!!